# How to multibind or patterns in match expressions?

Tags: rust, match

Is there a way of binding to the same name a bunch of or matchings?

So for example in the following code, I would like `n` to be any of the or matchs, `1`, `2` or `3`.

```rust
fn main() {
    match 2 {
        n @ 1 | 2 | 3 => {
            println!("{}", n);
        }
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03ef5dbe5453f1475d398106ffe15fef)

It complains with:

```
error[E0408]: variable `n` is not bound in all patterns
 --> src/main.rs:3:17
  |
3 |         n @ 1 | 2 | 3 => {
  |         -       ^   ^ pattern doesn't bind `n`
  |         |       |
  |         |       pattern doesn't bind `n`
  |         variable not in all patterns
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just surrounding the `or` match with `()` (parenthesis) makes the binding properly:

```rust
fn main() {
    match 2 {
        n @ (1 | 2 | 3) => {
            println!("{}", n);
        }
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a72cef219a0f541419ed0b6870f8bcf8)